# How to multiply the rows on a same column in a pyspark dataframe based on date/month?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, pivot

So basically I have a dataframe with two rows: the number of users on the first and the conversion rate for them on the second, like the table shown here:

```
df.show()
+---------+----------+----------+----------+                                       
| month   | company_1| company_2| company_3|
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| 02-2022 | 1000     | 5000     | 500      |
| 02-2022 | 0.08     | 0.13     | 0.45     |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I need to multiply users by conversion rate, so I can have the number of clients who bought something in that company each month, like the table shown here:

```
df.show()
+---------+----------+----------+----------+                                       
| month   | company_1| company_2| company_3|
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| 02-2022 | 80       | 650      | 225      |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I don't know how I can do that, could you guys help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your data frame have *only* two rows or is the actual data frame much larger?

Comment: There are two rows for each month of the year, but i only process two lines at a time so we can consider it as having only two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use groupby with product here:

Docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.product.html

```
df.groupBy("month").agg(*[F.product(col).alias(col) for col in cols]).show()
```

---

```
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|  month|company_1|company_2|company_3|
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|02-2022|     80.0|    650.0|    225.0|
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

For older versions of pyspark, you can do something similar to this using higher order functions available from spark 2.4+

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col!= "month"]
out = df.groupBy("month").agg(*[F.expr(f"""aggregate(collect_list({col}),
                                cast(1 as double),(value, acc) -> value * acc, 
                                acc -> acc) as {col}""") for col in cols])
```

---

```
out.show()
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|  month|company_1|company_2|company_3|
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|02-2022|     80.0|    650.0|    225.0|
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: When I run this i get the following error:  AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.functions' has no attribute 'product'. This makes no sense, since i imported  pyspark.sql.functions as F

Comment: @MarcosDias what is your pyspark version? this was implemented in spark 3.2

Comment: Oh, that's why. I'm running 3.0.1.

Comment: @MarcosDias check my edit, added another way